# Inserting new item in UITableView leads to invalid number of sections

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm losing my mind here. Relevant code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [[self.currentWorkout movements] count];
}
```

And...

```
- (void)addMovement:(Movement *)movement{
    [self.currentWorkout.movements insertObject:movement atIndex:0];

    [self.table beginUpdates];
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [self.table endUpdates];
}
```

I have confirmed that `insertObject:atIndex:` is adding the object; the count of `currentWorkout` increases by one.

`Error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (8) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (7), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: using wrong method to insert sections.

```
- (void)addMovement:(Movement *)movement{
    [self.currentWorkout.movements insertObject:movement atIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%d",(int)[self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.table]);

    [self.table beginUpdates];
    [self.table insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [self.table endUpdates];
}
```

Removing the `[self.table beginUpdates];` method call is important because otherwise the table will think it has the number of rows it would get after adding the object before that object is actually added.